# Logic in Custom Activity Button

Tags: custom-button, activities, urlhacking

I want to create a single button to add to the Activity History related list on both leads and contacts. I've created the following button but am getting an error:

```
{!IF( Lead.Id != "",
"/00T/e?who_id={!Lead.Id}&followup=1&tsk5=SQL&retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}",
"/00T/e?who_id={!Contact.Id}&followup=1&tsk5=SQL&retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}")
}
```

The URL I'm redirected to is:
`https://xxxx.salesforce.com/servlet/%2F00T%2Fe%3Fwho_id%3D%7B%21Contact.Id%7D%26followup%3D1%26tsk5%3DSQL%26retURL%3D%252F%7B%21Contact.Id%7D`

An issue I'm seeing is that the url is escaping characters like "/" and "&" and the second is that `Contact.Id` isn't being filled in

I'm not sure how to resolve but would love advice!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are generating is a string, all in the context of the built in `IF` function.

So, to evaluate this calculation correctly, you need to only have one `{!}` binding syntax call for the whole calc (around the outside).

You then need to create strings and concatenate them with your lead variables (which don't need the binding syntax) - Think of the {!} as a signal to the VF compiler saying "Hey, evaluate this".

Your calc should look something like this:

```
{!IF( Lead.Id != "",
"/00T/e?who_id=" & Lead.Id & "&followup=1&tsk5=SQL&retURL=%2F" & Lead.Id ,
"/00T/e?who_id=" & Contact.Id & "&followup=1&tsk5=SQL&retURL=%2F" & Contact.Id)
}
```

The alternative is to use Javascript - in that case, you WOULD use the `{!}` binding syntax for each contact and lead reference - but you'd use a different `if` syntax.

Here is an example of the Javascript version (you'd use an "onclick javascript" button:

```
var leadId = '{!Lead.Id}';
var contactId = '{!Contact.Id}';

if (leadId != ''){
    window.location.href = "/00T/e?who_id=" + leadId +
                       "&followup=1&tsk5=SQL&retURL=%2F" + leadId;
}
else {
    window.location.href = "/00T/e?who_id=" + contactId +
                       "&followup=1&tsk5=SQL&retURL=%2F" + contactId;
}
```

Comment: This completely makes sense. I updated my code to look like yours and the IDs are being populated but the URL that's coming up is still escaping some characters `https://cs42.salesforce.com/servlet/%2F00T%2Fe%3Fwho_id%3D00Q56000001BkBg%26followup%3D1%26tsk5%3DSQL%26retURL%3D%252F00Q56000001BkBg`

Comment: What sort of button are you using? a commandButton? Can I see the code?

Comment: it's a URL button. I'm using the code you generated above.

Comment: Added an onclick javascript example